# Cómo usar una variable dentro de mi función?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

este es mi reproductor de video y funciona correctamente pero ahora quiero usar una variable dentro de mi función la cual devuelve un link del video desde la url ingresada y no se si el problema está al intentar extraer el link desde la url o al momento de querer usar la variable en mi función. Agradecería mucho la ayuda, este es mi código:

```
<script>
        var url = new "'" + URLSearchParams(window.location.search) + "'";
        var link = url.get('link');

        jwplayer("container").setup({
            controls: true,
            displaytitle: false,
            fullscreen: "true",
            primary: 'html5',
            stretching: "exactfit",
            autostart: false,
            playlist:[{
                image: "",
                sources:[{
                    file: link,
                    'type': 'mp4',
                    primary: 'html5'
                }]
            }]
        });
 </script>
```

Comment: Intenta quitar esos strings que concatenas, no tiene sentido ponerlos, solo generarian problemas puesto que siempre despues de la palabra reservada new debe haber un objeto extendible. lo otro es... porque usas window.location.search?, si bien es posible definir esa propiedad con un valor lo cierto es que es mejor no alterar las propiedades de la ventana, deberías considerar definir esa variable en otra parte y no en la ventana, por ejemplo en una variable definidad por ti y no una que hace parte de los componentes que vienen de fabrica en javascript.

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en esto :), el parametro de la url (www.pagina.com/?link=https://www.vaimeo.com/592374823) seria el parametro "link" entonces si no concateno las comillas en la variable para hacer referencia a que el video se reproduzca desde ese link donde lo podría hacer? 2. Hay alguna otra formas mas simple de extraer un parametro de la url? Muchas gracias

Comment: si hay una forma mas fácil. la variable llamada url que tienes puedes ponerle como valor: "www.pagina.com/?link=vaimeo.com/592374823" asi tal cual con comillas, de esa manera no tienes que ponerte a instanciar cosas, simplemente usas la url tal cual pasandole a tu funcion como parametro la variable url.

Comment: Ah claro entiendo, sucede que quiero poner diferentes url de videos y que el script busque el link que pongo en el parametro de la url. De esa forma puedo reproducir cualquier video solo cambiando el parametro de la url.

Comment: Tambien tienes que mirar si aquello que estas usando permite usar ese parametro link como url para que te traiga videos diferentes, el parametro link de tu url es bien recibido por vimeo?

Comment: Esa era una url de ejemplo, la url correcta seria esta: https://storage.googleapis.com/eng-ridge-274919.appspot.com/d1fbde212eafb622bab0a3a9abb12213.mp4 la cual me funciona bien agregándola dentro del código, pero al momento de querer extraerla del parametro de la url no me funciona.

Comment: Ummm podrias colocar la funcion que se encarga de recoger la URL para editarla?, o por ejemplo el codigo de URLSearchParams, es complicado llegar a la solucion si no podemos ejecutar jwplayer, no se si depronto dentro de URLSearchParams estas transformando la URL o algo, o estas intentando hacer algo, depronto eso puede ayudar y darnos mas pistas.

Answer (score 0):

intenta esto:

```
<script>
        var url = "www.pagina.com/?link=vaimeo.com/592374823";

        jwplayer("container").setup({
            controls: true,
            displaytitle: false,
            fullscreen: "true",
            primary: 'html5',
            stretching: "exactfit",
            autostart: false,
            playlist:[{
                image: "",
                sources:[{
                    file: url,
                    'type': 'mp4',
                    primary: 'html5'
                }]
            }]
        });
 </script>
```

**Hay que mirar bien en el codigo que ha cambiado.**

Si deseas agregar parametros a una **url** basta como lo estas haciendo, es decir, para el primer parametro poner:

```
?parametro=valor
```

Si quieres agregar mas de un parametro, la **url** se veria de la siguiente manera:

```
www.pagina.com/?link=vaimeo.com&segundo_parametro=segundo_valor&etc=etc_valor
```

De hecho no se si tu **URL** es valida, me trae sospechas esta **URL**:

```
www.pagina.com/?link=vaimeo.com/592374823
```

**no hablo del dominio**, puesto que se sabe que solo es un ejemplo, hablo de que los parametros por **URL** normalmente van **al final de la ruta**, en tu link los tienes en el medio, y creo que eso no es valido.

Comment: La url es esta https://storage.googleapis.com/eng-ridge-274919.appspot.com/d1fbde212eafb622bab0a3a9abb12213.mp4 y quiero poder cambiar la url solo con escribirlo en el parametro pero hasta el momento no me funciona